# Redis Subscribe and SignalR Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, redis, signalr

I was wondering if there was an established pattern for doing what I'm trying to achieve. It seems a fairly common scenario so I'd be surprised if there wasn't, however I'm unable to find anything. The main technologies I'm using:

- ASP.NET MVC4
- SignalR
- Redis (using the ServiceStack API)

I would like to subscribe to messages from Redis and publish these to end-users using SignalR.

Rather than setting up a new Redis connection for each end-user, I would like to maintain one subscription per topic/channel. Each topic would then have its own SignalR hub, which the end-users would subsequently subscribe to. So essentially redis topic --> signalR hub --> many users.

My questions revolves around how to maintain these subscriptions. They are (by nature) blocking, which is a problem when dealing with web applications. Is it safe for me to simply create a separate thread to handle each topic's subscription, or is there a better way of doing this? Or have I misinterpreted the problem entirely?

I'm fairly new to web development, so any thoughts would be appreciated.